# Module 'Razorpay' has no member named 'initWithKey' in swift

Tags: ios, swift, razorpay

I am new in iOS and I am using `Xcode 12.3` I am facing issue with razorpay Since I updated my Xcode. I Updated my Razorpay to `'razorpay-pod', '~> 1.1.12'` but it shows still the same issue.
Did someone face this issue and is there is any solution to resolve it.Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/ios-integration/standard/

> Use Variable RazorpayCheckout for Swift versions 5.1+:
> For Swift version 5.1+, ensure that you declare var razorpay: RazorpayCheckout!. For versions lower than 5.1, you may use var razorpay: Razorpay!.

> Alternatively, you can use the following alias and retain the variable as Razorpay.

> typealias Razorpay = RazorpayCheckout

You should switch to `RazorpayCheckout` from `Razorpay`.

```
razorpay = RazorpayCheckout.initWithKey(razorpayTestKey, andDelegate: self)
```

Comment: Thank you!  You save my day.